# AMPscript not working in subject line - Removing first 2 '%' characters

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio

I'm using a very simple AMPscript personalization in the subject line. Specifically `%%First Name%%`.

It displays fine in the preview section, but when I perform the actual test send, the subject line displays as "First Name%%, example subject line"

What am I doing wrong?
See images below:

1. Subject Line Settings in Email Studio
2. Subject Line Preview in Preview and Test mode
3. Actual Subject Line in inbox

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your test send are you adding a prefix like `[Test]` to the subject line? if so be sure you have a space or another character after the ].

What is occurring is your subject line looks like `[Test]%%First Name%%`

Since `]%%`is a closing ampscript block the system is reading it as such.

I would either add a space or a : to the end of the test prefix `[Test]:%%First Name%%`

Comment: You're a champion for seeing and thinking about this!!! Problem solved. Thank you soo much, this was driving me mad!

Answer (score 3):

When using Data extension fields for personalization within an email. If the field has space's you need to wrap the field with square brackets `[]`.

So in your case, the data extension field is `First Name`

The Personalization String for this should be `%%[First Name]%%`

Comment: If I add the square brackets surrounding 'First Name'(`%%[First Name]%%`), it does not output anything, and I'm left with ' , no one can be left behind' in the inbox. I find it strange that the built-in subject line personalization feature in content builder uses %%First Name%%, but that's removing the first 2 '%' symbols in the inbox.